# Pattern for global object in React Native

Tags: javascript, oop, react-native

Is there a well-established pattern for allowing a single object to be available to all modules in a React Native application? I know I can pass the object from the RouteMapper to every particular scene and access it that way, but that feels like a lot of boilerplate and repeated code when I am absolutely certain that I need it accessible from the entire application. In fact, I need it listening for events at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is the React Context.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html
But the general wisdom is: don't use it.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Luckily they say that passing the currently logged-in user is an acceptable use case, and I'm really just passing the user with some user-attached event listeners, so I think I'll be okay for now.

I'll accept your answer if nothing else is forthcoming.